# Запись в файл элементов структуры сначала в начало, затем в конец. Этот код работает не так

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            f << student[i].name << endl;
            f << student[i].GPU << endl;
        }
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            f << student[n - i].name << endl;
            f << student[n - i].GPU << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вам следует разбить на партиции исходный массив структур согласно критерию четный-нечетный и последовательно его записывать в файл.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то имеется два подхода к ее решению.

Первый - это упорядочить массив, разбив его на две партиции, когда в начале массива будут располагаться все "четные" элементы, а затем все "нечетные" элементы. И тогда вы просто можете записывать элементы результирующего массива последовательно.

Для разбиения массива на партиции вы можете использовать стандартные алгоритмы `std::partition`  или `std::stable_partition`, объявленные в заголовочном файле `<algorithm>`.

Второй подход состоит в том, что вы по исходному массиву делаете два прохода. Сначала из него записываете все "четные" элементы, а затем при втором проходе в цикле записываете все "нечетные" элементы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но тут надо сделать следующее. Я ввожу сначала одну запись в конец, затем ввожу в начало файла. И почему-то при четном количестве элементов он мне выдает 11, 44, 33, 22. Т. е. при четном количестве вводимых элементов он отрабатывает правильно

Comment: Просто я сделал так: Мне надо чередованием вводить в файл в конец-в начало. Я просто так разбил потому, что нулевой элемент лучше объежинять с четными элементами массива

Comment: @user6448834 Вы не можете вводить в начало, а затем в конец файла, а затем снова в начало.  Файл записывается последовательно запись за записью в конец файла.

Comment: Я сначала просто ввел значения в поля структуры последовательно один за одним. И затем уже при записи в файл записываю первый элемент структуры, затем последний, затем второй, затем предпоследний. Я наверно неправильно описал задачу. Структура заполнена допустим числами 11(имя студента) и к нему пара 11(средний балл). Последний вводимый студент 44 - 44. У меня работает данный код почему-то толкьо с четным количеством вводимых студентов

Answer (score 1):

Замените `[n-i]` на `[n-i-n%2]`, и все у вас получится...

Просто посмотрите - сделав руками несколько циклов - что у вас получается при четных и при нечетных `n`...